# Views: CSS Style

Tags: 7, views, theming

Normally when I create views, I will change the style at style.css. Example: #block-views-example{ margin: 0px auto; }. In the views, I see some styles setting. Am I able to just set the style setting there? Example: style.css .margin0px {margin: 0px auto} and just place class="margin0px" in the views style setting. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views style setting will allow you to assign classes on the style settings ( .margin0px), choose wrapper whether div, span or something else. So yes, if you're going to put your class on the views style setting that is possible.

[image]

Comment: Haha Nice. Find out an easy way to style views. Thanks. By the way, do you know how to remove bullet in the view? I add the image and realize there is bullet at the left side.

Comment: Welcome. :) Where did you put the image? is it an image field? or css style? normally there should be no bullet. can you give a screenshot?

Comment: I had solve. My views format is html list. That is the reason there is bullet. I had change format to Unformatted list and work well. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just add a style sheet to my theme. Every page/node can be accessed and filtered with a class in front of the class you want to edit.

There is also the possibility to edit styles with the help of Emmet Livestyle extension in Chrome. In combination with Sublime text editor you can edit your css live in chrome and the result is directly saved in one the theme files. So changing your style.css can be still a good method.

If you new to css i suggest to take a look at http://sass-lang.com/